# ValueError: 60 columns passed, passed data had 282 columns

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

They show me the error `ValueError: 60 columns passed, passed data had 282 columns` how to solve these error  this is the page link https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202110190MIL.html if you go to page that click `Q1` and scrape the  1 table as you shown in pic[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

#put all item in this array
temp = []
response = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202110190MIL.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table', class_='sortable stats_table')
headers=[tup.text for tup in table.find_all("th")]


for row in table:
    temp.append([row.text for row in table.find_all('td')])

df = pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=headers)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beautifulsoup` answer

```
table=soup.select_one('table#box-BRK-game-basic')
headers=[tup.text for tup in table.select("thead tr:nth-of-type(2) th")]

for row in table.tbody.select('tr:not(.thead)'):
    cells=[cell.text for cell in row.children]
    temp.append(cells)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's easier to just read the page directly with pandas:

```
tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
```

This gives you 16 tables, for both teams, both basic and advanced, headers, totals and all.